# How can I import a Postman collection to replace a forked instance of that collection?

Tags: json, api, postman

I have been tasked with doing an extensive refactor of a fairly large Postman collection. To do a bulk of this work, I wanted to export the Postman collection to a .json file to do some string replacements on before importing it back in. This collection is in active use, so I want to be able to test my changes before making a pull request into the original collection using Postman's built in version control. The problem here is that when I go to import the collection back into the app, it wants to replace the original collection instead of my fork.

My steps that have led me to this situation are as follows:

1. Create a fork of the "Company APIs" collection.
2. Make a number of changes to folder structure, write a few scripts, etc.
3. Export the forked collection to a json file. Make a number of bulk string changes using my local text editor.
4. Attempt to import the collection back into postman. Risk clobbering the original collection and therefore my change process for the fork.

I tried performing the above process with a trivial change as a test, and can confirm that re-importing the collection replaces the original "Company APIs" collection, and not my fork of it.

Thank you.